# C# Designer File: Error rendering control. Designer file is not Being Generated correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking at this for days. I have tried every option in the book and on the web, but have no luck.

There were no changes to the code where I am getting the error, but the designer file is out of sync. To me it seems like the NoteEditor.ascx.cs file can't read its control file NoteDetail.ascx.cs.

I am not sure why, I have tried deleting the designer file and recreating it. I tried closing all the project tabs and Visual Studio and reopened it, recreated the Designer files with no luck.

The error is that some controls don't have definitions even though they are all defined.

Here is an Error For ReturnUrl in the Note Editor it is used as the following code:

```
NoteDetail.ReturnUrl = Globals.NavigateURL("", Literals.urlInstalledItemId + "=" + installedItemIdAsString);
```

and the method is defined in NoteDetail.ascx.cs:

```
public string ReturnUrl { get { return (string)ViewState[vsReturnUrl]; } set { ViewState[vsReturnUrl] = value; } }
```

I built the project and it was successful but, rebuilt it again and the error for all the methods within these 2 files were detected. The designer file is definitely out of sync, I tried changing the control file location and ID name of the controllers with no luck.

The Main Issue here is that NoteEditor and NoteDetail Are NOT seeing each other Methods and Definitions. Even though they both inherit from each other.

Any Help IS appreciated guys. Thank You.

Comment: Are they on the same namespace?

Comment: they are on the same name space: NoteDetail is `namespace MyProject.Modules.Project.Controls` and NoteEditor is on :`namespace MyProject.Modules.Dnn.Project`

Comment: `Even though they both inherit from each other`.  That's not possible.

Comment: I see. So, @user5711432, Instead of regenerating the designer file into another, have you tried recreating the whole fileset? I mean, create another file and placed the code piece by piece?

Comment: Ok, Should I create the File in the same Location, Or it will be and better and a more effective approach to change the the location of the control file? what do You Think? Let me know. regarding recreating the whole file set, I did try that, the files exist in separate folder under the same project, should I have them under the same Folder would that make a difference??